# Kubernetes NGINX Ingress Controller 404 Not found / Object not found

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, nginx-config

I am taking a course in Udemy and I am new to the world of **Kubernetes** and I am trying to configure **ingress nginx controller** in Kubernetes but it returns **404 not found** when i send a request at specified URL, it has been 10 days that I am trying to fix it, i've looked at similar questions but none of their answers are working for me. I am also using **Skaffold** to do build/deploy image on docker hub automatically when i change something in files.

[image: 404 not found screenshot]

My **express app** server:

```
app.get('/api/users/currentuser', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hi there');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('[Auth] - Listening on port 3000');
});
```

**ingress-srv.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticketing.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

**auth-depl.yaml** (Auth deployment & srv)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: myusername/auth:latest
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

**skaffold.yaml** file:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta25
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: username/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . . 

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I also executed command from [NGINX Ingress Controller docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/):

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.0.5/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

I also changed hosts.file in the system:
127.0.0.1 ticketing.com

Logs:

**kubectl get pods**

```
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
auth-depl-5f89899d9f-wtc94   1/1     Running   0          6h33m
```

**kubectl get svc**

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
auth-srv     ClusterIP   10.96.23.71   <none>        3000/TCP   23h
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1     <none>        443/TCP    25h
```

**kubectl get pods --namespace=ingress-nginx**

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-7fm56        0/1     Completed   0          23h
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-5vflr         0/1     Completed   1          23h
ingress-nginx-controller-5c8d66c76d-89zhp   1/1     Running     0          23h
```

**kubectl get ing**

```
NAME          CLASS    HOSTS           ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
ingress-srv   <none>   ticketing.com   localhost   80      23h
```

**kubectl describe ing ingress-srv**

```
Name:             ingress-srv
Namespace:        default
Address:          localhost
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host           Path  Backends
  ----           ----  --------
  ticketing.com
                 /api/users/?(.*)   auth-srv:3000 (10.1.0.10:3000)
Annotations:     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                 From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    22m (x18 over 23h)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

Could there be a problem with the Windows IIS web server? since I previously configured something for another project, and in the screenshot above I see:

```
Requested URL      http://ticketing.com:80/api/users/currentuser
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\api\users\currentuser
```

Also the screenshot shows the port **:80** at the requested URL but I have the server port 3000? + when i request at **https** it returns:

```
502 Bad Gateway
nginx
```

also C:\inetpub\wwwroot is strange to me.

Any ideas would help me a lot with continuing the course.

Comment: All setup look good. Yes, it can be the issue, since `404` on the screenshot above is returned by IIS. Is there any option to turn off the IIS temporary? How is your kubernetes cluster installed? `ingress nginx` is listening on port `80` - you can find it under `kubectl get ing`. Also it won't change anything, but `Dockerfile` doesn't have `EXPOSE` directive.

Comment: @moonkotte - I solved it early today, all the time I thought the problem might be there but I never got the courage to try it. I turned off IIS on windows features and it works now, I posted the solution. Thanks for the comment, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a few days of research I finally solved the problem, the problem was with IIS Web Server which I had enabled when I was working on a project in ASP.NET core, I uninstalled it and the problem was solved.

How to uninstall IIS from Windows 10:

- Go to Control Panel > Programs and Features
- Click Turn Windows features on or off
- Scroll down to Internet Information Services
- Click on the square next to Internet Information Services so it becomes empty
- Click OK and restart the PC (required).